# How can I get Eclipse CDT to generate a C++ class constructor from data members?

Tags: c++, eclipse, constructor, code-generation, eclipse-cdt

I've recently started using Eclipse Kepler CDT. I'd like to be able to generate code for a class constructor, after having typed in the class data members. Using Eclipse to write Java development, I would do this by right-clicking and using the constructor generation entry in the Source sub-menu (Alt+Shift+S); writing C++, though, this functionality is not available... or is it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The feature is NOT in CDT yet.

I've been envying the Eclipse JDT (Java) for the feature of "Generate constructor using fields" for years. 8o  It saves so~ much time for boiler plate code.

If you like this feature too, please **Vote it up** together with your friends/colleagues in the following page!
https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=306902#c4

So that we can all have this feature in next release!

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: I see your point but I do not agree deleting it. 

- I've edited answer to make it clear that the feature is not there yet.

- Features don't add themselves. My suggestion of voting it up is a way to provide the feature to @einpoklum and everyone.

- Maybe you judged a bit too fast when assuming that I'm not answering the question.

Comment: PS: I feel this forum is now too harsh on moderating. People tend to like judging others and punish others by "rule XYZ" without 2nd thought. In this case, I think I understand what @einpoklum was talking about as I've been using Eclipse CDT for years. If someone disagrees, shouldn't he verify with author before punishing?

Comment: That's your main misconception. This is **NOT** a forum. And we are not criticising people, just the content they post. We realise that a new member of this site cannot instantly be an expert on all the rules, but we do expect that these rules are followed and any content that is in violation of these rules is unwanted. This is a site for professional and enthusiast programmers, as such the content here is expected to adhere to a certain level of quality, if it does not measure up, it needs to either be improved, or deleted.

Comment: Relevant discussions regarding these topics on meta: [**Why is Stack Overflow so negative as of late?**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251758/why-is-stack-overflow-so-negative-of-late) and [**Question Quality is dropping on Stack Overflow**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252506/question-quality-is-dropping-on-stack-overflow) and many more.

Comment: To summarise: We are not intentionally mean to new members, they just get more things wrong as they have no experience with Stack Overflow and we point those errors out regardless of who is making them. You have to understand that we are trying to preserve a high level of quality so Stack Overflow can remain the important resource it is for many programmers. But we have to stem a huge tide of low quality content, duplicates, off topic questions and spam and sorting through all that to get to the occasional good question is very straining.

Comment: Thanks. I misused a word. But I AM giving a valid answer and it is to the point.

Comment: Yes you are and it wasn't me who down voted your answer in the first place. Although I do understand why one might want to. You have to be careful with short answers especially when they are not programming related and that link didn't make your answer look any more appealing. Again, there is nothing wrong with your answer in its current state, but especially before you edited it and if you don't pay that much attention it can come off as somewhat promotional and off topic, but I would say that this is more of the questions fault. Perhaps this is not the perfect question for you to answer...

Comment: In the long run it pays off more to take your time with your answer and especially in the beginning you should try to avoid short answers. Carefully pick the questions you want to answer until you figured out how to ask and answer. Avoid low quality questions because low quality questions mostly attract equally low quality answers.

Comment: This wasn't a low quality question (OP asked, "how do I do X?"), and the response was not low quality (Answer: "You can't, yet").

Comment: Thanks @IraBaxter! Could you help me vote the answer up, if not too much trouble?

Comment: @XaverKapeller, hope you can revoke your downvote if you did. The issue is someone just don't have a 2nd thought before downvoting a post by someone with low rep. They just don't take time to think. I bet they dare NOT if this account have 200k rep. ^^

Comment: @Bill No rep has nothing to do with it. While it may get some people to check again if they misinterpreted something ultimately it doesn't matter how much rep you have. If there is something wrong with your post then you will get down votes and no amount of rep is going to keep you safe from that. This site is about accumulating as much good content as possible and not about accumulating content from high rep users. I have seen completely off topic and spam posts from 100k+ rep users and while I admit that it is kind of funny to come across such a post it doesn't influence my decision.

Comment: @Bill And no I did not down vote your post but for the future: Votes are locked in after a 10-15 minute grace period. Only after the post has been edited one can once again change his vote.

Comment: @Bill: I can assure you, there are many folks at SO that will downvote so-called "high rep" users.